# How do I use AWS EKS with the Jenkins Kubernetes Cloud plugin?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks

I have found essentially no documentation about how to use the [Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin) with Amazon EKS. The [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes) mentions aws-iam-authenticator and a java setting to change a cache timeout, but doesn't explain how to configure anything.

If I put the API URL for my EKS cluster in the "Kubernetes URL" field and click the "Test Connection" button I get an error about the certification path:

```
Error testing connection https://XXX.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If I then check the "Disable https certificate check" checkbox I get an error about the "system:anonymous" user not having the right permissions:

```
Error testing connection https://XXX.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com: Failure executing: GET at: https://XXX.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default". Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=pods, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default", metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Forbidden, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

The EC2 instance the jenkins master is running on has an IAM role with full eks:* permissions. If I set up a Credential with the IAM Role it doesn't show up in the Credentials dropdown. A Credential with an AWS access and secret key also doesn't show up in the Credentials dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Been there and resolved that.

If you've setup your kubeconfig to use `aws eks get-token ..`, then ensure your Jenkins Master has AWS CLI version 1.16.300 and up which supports fetching a token with aws-cli.

If you've setup your kubeconfig to use `aws-iam-authenticator`, then ensure you've installed the AWS IAM Authenticator on the Jenkins master and that the `jenkins` user is able to use the binary (path settings).

This should get your past the 'system:anonymous' error during connection testing.

And finally, if you're hitting an error along the lines of `Unauthorized! Token may have expired! Please log-in again. Unauthorized.`, then you need to ensure two things:

1. Ensure the plugin version for kubernetes-plugin is atleast 1.23.2. This will require a Jenkins version of atleast 2.190.1. This version is required for the step that follows.
2. This java setting is set in Jenkins Java options as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#running-with-a-remote-kubernetes-cloud-in-aws-eks): `JAVA_ARGS="-Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.clients.cacheExpiration=60"`. The default for this is 24 hours, whereas EKS expires tokens every 15 minutes. This setting for 60 clears the token every 60 seconds.
   `